# Searching object arraylist confusion

Tags: java, search, methods, parameters, arraylist

I wrote a method for searching an object in my arralist, however I need this search to take two parameters and compare them to the description of the object. What it is confusing me is that I do not know how to make my method take two parameter and those two parameters compare to one single description.
 e.g  Description of object: Blue Mustang

Now the search method has to take two parameters in this case one String "Blue" and one String "Mustang" and I do not have a clue how to do it. I found a way to just write the complete description as one parameter and works perfectly. I am leaving the method that I tried to change to look for two parameters and as well the method that takes one parameter and works fine. It is important to mention that the method also needs to look for cars that are not on loan so thats why there is also a comparison to the hire date since if the car is on loan will have one and if not it wouldn't.

Trying to change it to look for two parameters:

```
public Car searchCar(String description, String description2)
{
    for (Car car : cars) {
        if (car.getDescription().equals(description) && car.getDescription().equals(description2) && car.getHireDate().equals("")) {

            System.out.println( ": " + car.getDescription() + " rate: £" + car.getDailyRate() + " Down payment: £"+ car.getDownPayment());
            return car;

        }
        else if (car.getHireDate() != ("")) {
            System.out.println("This car is rented!!");
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is the one that takes one parameter and works fine:

```
public Car searchCar(String description)
{
    for (Car car : cars) {
        if (car.getDescription().equals(description) && car.getHireDate().equals("")) {

            System.out.println( ": " + car.getDescription() + " rate: £" + car.getDailyRate() + " Down payment: £"+ car.getDownPayment());
            return car;

        }
        else if (car.getHireDate() != ("")) {
            System.out.println("This car is rented!!");
        }
        else {

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do you want _exact_ matches or all objects _containing_ the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

description needs to be identical to  description2
you could do :

```
String fulldescription=description+" "+description2;
```

and then

```
if (car.getDescription().equals(fulldescription)...
```

a different approach can be

```
 if (car.getDescription().indexOf(description)>0 && car.getDescription().indexOf(description2)>0 )...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely the description would be exactly equal to both parameters. Perhaps you're trying to match only *part* of the description?

Something like [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) might be of interest.

Also note that this line:

```
else if (car.getHireDate() != ("")) {
```

will not work as you expect; you correctly compare strings in the previous statement (using `equals`) but fail to do so here.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should define whether exact matches are necessary or if the parameters should be contained and there might be additional text in the description.

*Exact matches*

For exact matches, you can use the or-condition:

```
if ( (car.getDescription().equals(description) | car.getDescription().equals(description2) ) && car.getHireDate().equals("") ) {
   ... 
}
```

This means that if the description *exactly* matches `description` *or* `description2` you get a hit.

Alternatively you could concatenate the parameters if you know the order:

```
if ( car.getDescription().equals(description + " " + description2) && car.getHireDate().equals("") ) {
   ... 
}
```

This would match "Blue Mustang" but not "Mustang Blue".

Optionally you could make the concatenated string a regular expression in order to allow for arbitrary whitespace:

```
if ( car.getDescription().matches("\\s*\\b" + description + "\\b\\s*\\b" + description2 + "\\b\\s*") && car.getHireDate().equals("") ) {
   ... 
}
```

This would match "     Blue   Mustang    " etc. but not "BlueMustang" due to the word boundary requirements (`"\\b"`).

Note that there are many more possibilities so you should define how you want to match first.

*Parameters contained*

If you want to get all descriptions that *contain* both parameters, use `contains(...)` instead:

```
if ( car.getDescription().contains(description) && car.getDescription().contains(description2) && car.getHireDate().equals("") ) {
   ... 
}
```

Note that this would match "Blue Ford Mustang", too ("Blue" and "Mustang" being the parameters).

Answer (score 0):

In order to test for the occurence of substrings, you can use [`indexOf()` (docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29):

```
if (-1 != car.getDescription().indexOf(description) && 
    -1 != && car.getDescription().indexOf(description2) &&
    car.getHireDate().equals("")) {
```

you might want to make the comparison case-insensitive too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use `contains` and `toLowerCase` for String search. Also consider a **variable argument search** method like this:

```
public Car searchCar(String...descriptions) {
    for (Car car : cars) {
        if (car.getHireDate().equals("")) {
            for (String d : descriptions) {
               // assuming car.getDescription() != null
               if (car.getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(d.toLowerCase())) {
                  System.out.println( ": " + car.getDescription() + " rate: £" + car.getDailyRate() + " Down payment: £"+ car.getDownPayment());
                  return car;
               }
            }
        }
        else
            System.out.println("This car is rented!!");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you can call this method like:

```
Car c1 = searchCar("blue");
```

OR

```
Car c1 = searchCar("blue", "toyota");
```

OR

```
Car c1 = searchCar("blue", "red", "toyota", "mustang", "honda");
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider encapsulating your search/match in a class which you can augment to include whatever search criteria you require.

Here is an example which satisfies your current requirements.

```
 class CarSearch {

    private boolean isIncludeHired;
    private String[] descriptionWords;
    private boolean isCaseInsensitive;

    public void setIncludeHired(boolean b) {
        isIncludeHired = b;
    }

    public void setCaseInsensitive(boolean b) {
        this.isCaseInsensitive = b;
    }

    public void setDescriptionWords(String[] words) {
        this.descriptionWords = words;
    }

    public boolean matches(Car car) {

        boolean matches = true;

        if (!isIncludeHired) {
            if (car.getHireDate() != null) {
                matches = false;
            }
        }

        if (matches && descriptionWords != null) {
            String description = car.getDescription();
            if (isCaseInsensitive) {
                description = description.toLowerCase();
            }
            boolean allMatch = true;
            for (String word: descriptionWords) {
                if (isCaseInsensitive) {
                    word = word.toLowerCase();
                }
                if (!description.contains(word)) {
                    allMatch = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            matches = allMatch;
        }

        return matches;
    }

    public List<Car> search(List<Car> cars) {
        List<Car> matched = new ArrayList<Car>();

        for (Car car: cars) {
            if (matches(car)) {
                matched.add(car);
            }
        }
        return matched;
    }
}
```

So now you could do something this:

```
    CarSearch search = new CarSearch();
    search.setCaseInsensitive(true);
    search.setIncludeHired(false);
    search.setDescriptionWords(new String[]{"blue", "mustang"});

    List<Car> matches = search.search(cars);
```

You could also easily change your `CarSearch` class to allow other things, e.g. exact match, search by hire date, search by registration, etc.